# How to open file in windows 10 default app from powershell

Tags: powershell, uwp, automation

I am trying to write a simple shell script in powershell that opens a file in a default windows app and monitors the process to wait until the process has exited to continue. At a high level I would like to open a .mp4 file to trim it in the default windows 10 app. When manually editing the file it opens in the photos app to trim, I would like to automate the part of opening the file in the app.

Currently I'm able to monitor the photos app process and wait for the process to close using the following code:

```
Start-Process shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
$proc = Get-Process -Name Microsoft.Photos
$proc.WaitForExit()
```

However I would like to start the process and pass in a filepath to open, for example:

```
Start-Process shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App "C:\Some\Path\To\File.mp4"
```

If I can get the file to simply open in the photos app I can simply click the edit button manually but ideally I would be able to open the file in the edit UI like this:

[image]

Then the script would wait for the photos process to close to continue on. Does anyone have any ideas on how we can open a file in a default windows 10 app in this way from powershehll? Or if this is even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps are not command line friendly, you'd have a better time with something like ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should explore the -Wait option of the Start-Process cmdlet

```
Start-Process "C:\Some\Path\To\File.mp4" -Wait
```